# Shared memory on system GLPI

Tags: linux, memory, ram

Hello I have installed system GLPI on my virtual server (version glpi 9.1.5) on this server I have 1999 MB ram:

[image]

In my system glpi I see used only 128MB:

[image]

How I can to increase this limit ? For example 256 MB ?

Comment: You have to give RAM to your virtual machine using the Virtual Machine Manager with which you created the virtual machine.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson I added 1GB now I have 3GB ram, but on system glpi still I have 100% used memory and still I have 128MB (I restarted server)

Comment: Can you run the command "free" on your VM, and post the output

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson Yes, please: http://iv.pl/images/32707279692182777683.png I don't know why I still have 128MB shared

Answer (score 0):

128 shared means nothing.

Your server is using **1737MB** of RAM, the shared column does not show how much RAM you are using.

If you see the man page of `free`:

```
free displays the total amount of free and used physical and swap memory in the system, as well as the buffers and caches used by  the  kernel.  The  information  is  gathered by parsing /proc/meminfo. The dis‐
       played columns are:

       total  Total installed memory (MemTotal and SwapTotal in /proc/meminfo)

       used   Used memory (calculated as total - free - buffers - cache)

       free   Unused memory (MemFree and SwapFree in /proc/meminfo)

       shared Memory used (mostly) by tmpfs (Shmem in /proc/meminfo)

       buffers
              Memory used by kernel buffers (Buffers in /proc/meminfo)

       cache  Memory used by the page cache and slabs (Cached and SReclaimable
              in /proc/meminfo)

       buff/cache
              Sum of buffers and cache

       available
              Estimation  of  how  much  memory  is available for starting new
              applications, without swapping. Unlike the data provided by  the
              cache  or  free fields, this field takes into account page cache
              and also that not all reclaimable memory slabs will be reclaimed
              due to items being in use (MemAvailable in /proc/meminfo, avail‐
              able on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels 2.6.27+, otherwise the
              same as free)
```